# How to add multiple properties of the same name to a dynamic in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, data-structures, dynamic

I have a `dynamic` say d. I am adding some properties to it by doing the following:

```
((IDictionary<String, Object>)d).Add("Propname", Propvalue);
```

Now, when i have properties that have the same name , this obviously throws an exception. I want to allow all the properties even if they are of the same name. So, the Dictionary is a wrong choice of Data Structure . I was thinking about the BAG equivalent of JAVA in C#. I could not find anything . What is the best way of going about this ?

Comment: Please confirm that you use "dynamic" in genral meaning (not C# `dynamic` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx ).

Comment: i am using C# dynamic ...is there a different tag for that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be completely mixing several concepts.

`dynamic` is a trigger that makes compiler generate late-bound code. Although it's not verified in compile-time, it follows the same rules as the ordinary c# code. It cannot have multi-valued properties (can you have them wherever in .NET?). The only way is having a collection-valued property and adding new values to the collection. Something like this:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.SomeProperty = new List<object>();

obj.SomeProperty.Add(SomeValue);
obj.SomeProperty.Add(AnotherValue);

foreach(var somePropertyValue in obj.SomeProperty)
{
  DoSmth(somePropertyValue);
}
```

`dynamic` has nothing to do with `IDictionary` or `Lookup`. A `dynamic` variable could be an arbitrary object, for instance an `int` value. If you use `dynamic`, it's **very** strange that you cast it to the `IDictionary` interface. Just call `Add` and the DLR will resolve the method for you (like I did above).

You should usually use `dynamic` only if you interoperate with a dynamic environment (script languages, COM, etc.). If you only work with c# code - throw away all the dynamic stuff and use regular .NET collections. It will both be statically verified by the compiler and work faster.

For example, you could use a `Dictionary<string, ICollection<object>>` to have a dynamic dictionary:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<object>>();
dictionary["SomeProperty"] = new List<object>();

dictionary["SomeProperty"].Add(SomeValue);
dictionary["SomeProperty"].Add(AnotherValue);

foreach(var somePropertyValue in dictionary["SomeProperty"])
{
  DoSmth(somePropertyValue);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Oh, yes, you could try creating your own `DynamicObject` implementation that would put values into a bag upon property assignment instead of overwriting the existing value. Specifically, you should override the [TrySetMember method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trysetmember.aspx). But first think if you really need all this complex stuff.

Comment: Yeah I assumed he was making his own DynamicObject implementation, and was just backing it with a Dictionary before.

Comment: @rally25rs Seems like you'd guessed since he accepted. Although I cannot understand how can `Lookup` be used for backing the `TrySetMember` if it is immutable. Can you?

Comment: Ah, yeah, your right. I hadn't used Lookup in a while, and forgot that Lookup itself is generated from another collection and stays immutable. I was thinking of it like a Dictionary, where you could just call .Add multiple times w/ the same key. oops... I actually would do it like you did in your example, where you have a `Dictionary<string, ICollection<object>>`

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure what you want the expected behavior to be, but if you want more than 1 item saved under the same property name, then you could use the [System.Linq.Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class instead of Dictionary.

Comment: i would like to add something like prop1 :somevalue , prop1 :somevalue2 to my dynamic ..will the  System.Linq.Lookup allow me to do that ?

Comment: It should, yes. It words similar to a `Dictionary` but doesn't enforce unique keys. When you get the value for a key, like `myLookup["prop1"]` it returns an `IEnumerable<T>` of values, instead of just 1 value like a Dictionary would.

Comment: Lovely, I didn't know of it. +1

Comment: `Lookup` won't help - it's an immutable class. You'll need to use one of the [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353368.aspx) method overloads to create the lookup.